# Apache Spark - Split Dataset Rows at Specific Line - Java/Pyspark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working through this initially in a Pyspark shell with plans to later write Java code to accomplish the same things.

I'm reading in a text file into a DataFrame.
    `df = spark.read.text("log.txt")`

The text file is a log file broken up into two sections delineated by a line containing a specific string. I would like to split the initial DataFrame into two separate DataFrames, one for each section. I've struggled to find info on this kind of manipulation of a DataFrame (sorting rows instead of columns.) My best guess is that the logic would look something like: find the row number with the string then create new DataFrames based on individual row numbers compared to the row number with the string. I don't know if this is actually efficient though.

Is this kind of thing doable with a DataFrame, and if so, how would I go about doing it? Would be more efficient to just read in the initial file line-by-line and create the two DataFrames there?

Comment: Before creating the Spark's `DataFrame`, could you not split your file into two different files, and create the `DataFrame` from them?

Comment: Well not manually, but yeah that would be an option. I think that might be the only way to do it too.